# House Rules for divine intervention

Tags: house-rules, munchkin

Last several games of munchkin were won via "divine intervention". All agree that the win is less satisfying than normal.

Does any have good house rules to make the card less onerous?

[image]

Comment: I'd say that random wins out of the blue are definitely part of the nature of Munchkin.

Comment: obviously the solution to that is to play a cleric.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of approaches that I can think of if it happens:

1. **Don't worry about it** - Shuffle up and play again. Random victories are part of the Munchkin experience. Or, if you'd rather play a deeper less swingy game, try out another game. Munchkin's fun, but maybe it's not perfect for you and your group. (I added this as a comment on the question, but thought it justified being part of an answer too.)
2. **Remove it from the game** - Pretty self-explanatory. If you consider it to be too powerful, just play without it.
3. **Prevent wins with it** - Modify it slightly. Allow clerics to gain a level, but say that it cannot be the winning level.

Hopefully one of these solutions will suit you.

Answer (score 5):

Another possibility is to just create house rules that will go along these lines:

1. Remove the card from the deck before play, and explain new players why.
2. Extend the amount of levels needed to win ie. 15-20 (this will only delay, but may help prevent surprise wins.)

Personally, I'd keep it! Although it sucks to lose to it, just deal with it and maybe luck will sway in your favor next game.

I've lost to it before, but because of Munchkin's randomness, I've come back from level 5 to win while 4 other players at level 9 were fighting each other and preventing each other from killing the winning monster.